# Android No peer certificate error on API 22

Tags: android, apache, http, peer

i have develop app that execute some different httpGet.
I execute one URL that works on Android 6 but on API 22 and 21 doesn't work and say me this error: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
the code is this:

```
private class HttpGetTask12 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {




    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    Double lat = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
    Double lon = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
    HttpClient mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    Context context;

    public HttpGetTask12(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    // ClusterManager<Car2GoClusterItem> mClusterManager;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.caricamento));
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {




        String SERVICE_URL = "https://api.hailoapp.com/drivers/near?latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+lon;

        String URL = SERVICE_URL;


        //HttpGet request_ = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpGet request_ = new HttpGet(URL);
        request_.setHeader("Authorization", "token " + token);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        Log.d("Hailo_url", ":" + URL);


        try {

            return mClient.execute(request_, responseHandler);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Why i have this error only on API 22 and 21 but not on ANdroid 6.
How i can fix this issues?
Thanks

Comment: You should use [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead. HttpClient was deprecated for some time and it's removed from recent SDK - you will not compile code targeting API 23+.

Comment: But with API 23 works fine. Not works on API 22 and 21

Comment: thanks for your reply, now works